# About the second largest adjacency eigenvalue of Abelian Cayley graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

[Assume all groups are finite]

One knows the general statement that the sum of the values of the character function on the generating set is an eigenvalue of a Cayley graph.

- But the above doesn't seem to automatically tell me anything about the ordering among the eigenvalues. Is there an expression or a method of calculating which will directly tell me something about the second largest adjacency eigenvalue of a Cayley graph? (At least when its Abelian?)
- Is there way to relate the second largest eigenvalue of a Cayley graph to the length of closed paths and/or the diameter of the Cayley graph or of the volume of of $n-$balls around the vertices? (Again any known simplification for the Abelian case?)

Comment: You should probably add that the group is abelian in the body of the question and not just in the title.

Comment: ... and that the groups are finite...

Comment: I made the necessary edits!

Answer (score 5):

Let $M$ be a $d\times m$ matrix over $GF(2)$ and let $X(M)$ be the graph on the binary vectors of length $d$, where two vectors are adjacent in their difference is a column of $M$. (This is a Cayley graph with valency $m$ on $2^d$ vertices.) The row space of $M$ is a binary code and $m-2k$ is an eigenvalue of $X(M)$ if and only if there is a code word of weight $k$ in this code. So to determine the second-largest eigenvalue of the Cayley graph, we must determine the minimum weight of the code. This is known to be an NP-hard problem.

There are bounds relating the diameter and spectrum, but I have not seen any improvement to these in the abelian case.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only connection I know between the second-largest adjacency eigenvalue ($\lambda_2$) and the diameter ($D$) is the Alon-Bopanna error term $\lambda_2 \geq 2 \sqrt{d-1}(1 - \frac{c}{D^2})$ Can this is specialized to the Cayley graph case by saying something like that the $D \leq log (\vert G \vert) $ ? (I am guessing the second inequality is true because every group has a generating set of size $O(log \vert G \vert )$)

Comment: If you google on "diameter eigenvalue graph" you will find a variety of bounds for graphs in general. These will tend not to be sharp because Cayley graphs for abelian groups with degree at three have low girth, and bounds just mentioned are sharpest when the girth is large.

Comment: I see a statement at places like that the only way a d-regular Abelian Cayley graph can lower its second adjacency eigenvalue by even $\epsilon d$ is by shooting up its degree to $log(\vert G \vert)$. I don't seem to have any intuition about this. Almost nothing I know about Cayley graphs has a "log" about it or even specific to Abelians.

Comment: The only so-called "proof" that I can see is by just plugging in this big result, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895605000948. I don't seem to see any other first-principles way of seeing it!

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate more on your answer? (1) Are you considering some $2^d$ sized Cayley graph of the group $GL_d(\mathbb{F}_2)$ over some generating set of $m$ elements? What is this generating set you have in mind? (2) What is this $k$ in your $m-2k$? From where are you getting this number $m-2k$? (3) Can you kindly give a reference to this known NP-hard question that you refer to about finding the minimum weight of code?

Comment: (4) Can you kindly state as to what is the precise formulation of the decision question from where you are reducing?

Comment: I don't see how an arbitrarily chosen matrix gets one the Cayley graph over $\mathbb{F}_2^d$ (group under XOR operation) that you seem to have in mind?

Comment: The vertices are binary vectors. Two vertices are adjacent if their difference is a column of the given matirx.

Comment: ^(1) So why is this a Cayley graph? You seem to be constructing an arbitrary graph (with as many vertices as the columns of the matrix i.e $m$) from the given binary matrix. (2) If somebody is given the graph adjacency matrix then it seems one can always find its eigenvalues in polynomial time. Then how does one understand this NP-Hardness?

Comment: The matrix is $d\times m$ (say). There are $2^d$ binary vectors and they form a group of order $2^d$. The graphs we get is a Cayley graph for this group, with valency $m$. The problem is to compute the eigenvalues in time polynomial in $n$.

Comment: I guess what you mean is this - you are reducing from a variant of the 'Minimum Distance over GF($2^m$)" NP-hard question at the bottom right of this paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=641542 - it seems that this question remains NP-hard if one restricts to matrices (of ``full rank") where among the $n$ $r-$length column vectors one is guaranteed to have $r$ linearly independent columns. Now one can use these $r-$ linearly independent columns to span $\mathbb{F}_2^r$.

Comment: Then for the group $\mathbb{F}_2^r$ these $r$ column vectors will form a generating set.

Comment: Though its not clear to me as to why this restriction on $\cal{H}$ keeps the question still NP-hard. (this looks natural but the proof is not

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Can you kindly collect your answer on this related question that I had put up (inspired from this discussion) http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31059/np-hardness-of-minimum-distance-over-a-code

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Given this arbitrary $M$ what assures that this $X(M)$ has any of the nice properties expected in a Cayley graph like being connected and undirected?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I think you can assure connectivity only if you choose those $d$ columns which are linearly independent as the generators for the Cayley graph over $\mathbb{F}_2^d$. But its not clear if your reduction needs the connectivity.